# How to add structured numbered outlines in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I'm new to using Google Docs as a word processor so maybe I'm missing something simple. I tried importing a word doc into Google Docs and it lost a lot of formatting. It turned my structured outline numbering (ie. 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, etc.) into just the last number, which is confusing when reading the document. Is there a way to fix this numbering style?

Comment: Are you referring to the formation of a Table of Contents?

Comment: Well, I have the table of contents working, but there is no auto numbering.

Comment: You can insert a page numbering via the menu: Insert/Page number, but you can't set it up the way you want to unfortunately.

Comment: I noticed that it also doesn't have the ability to add page numbers in the ToC. These are both basic word processor features going back decades. I don't understand how Google expects people to take them seriously while lacking features like this. Especially when they would be so easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer to a similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58166/36906). The [Table of Contents extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-of-contents/ickpeaanccmmabadbfiknbobkmkdnnaj?utm_source=permalink) does the trick.